# Combinatorics: list with alternative elements

Tags: python, numpy, combinatorics

I have a python list with 1D numpy arrays as elements, which have one or more elements. Consider each of the array elements as alternatives for the respective list element.

An example:

```
[array([1]),array([2]),array([2,3]),array([3]),array([4]),array([3,4,5])]
```

I want a two things:

**1)** All combinations regarding the alternatives:

```
array([[1,2,2,3,4,3],
       [1,2,3,3,4,3],
       [1,2,2,3,4,4],
       [1,2,3,3,4,4],
       [1,2,2,3,4,5],
       [1,2,3,3,4,5]])
```

**2.** The combination that has the least amount repetitions:

```
array([1,2,2,3,4,5])
```

or

```
array([1,2,3,3,4,5]).
```

The second should not be so hard to get, once one has the first thing, but I am not sure.

---

I would also like to use my more complex setups like

```
datasets_complete = [("iris1", iris1), ("iris2", iris2)]
percentages = [0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5]
imputers = [SimpleFill(), KNN(k=3), SoftImpute(), MICE()]
gridWidths = [0.1, 0.2]

seq = [datasets_complete, percentages, imputers, gridWidths]
testgrid = all_combinations(seq)
```

where iris1 and iris2 are pandas DataFrames.

Comment: Why does the question get downvoted? Please elaborate, so I can improve it.

Comment: @Divakar: I used yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a NumPy based approach -

```
def all_combs(a):          # Parte-1
    num_combs = np.prod(list(map(len,a)))
    return np.array(np.meshgrid(*a)).reshape(-1,num_combs).T

def get_minrep_combs(a):   # Parte-2
    out = all_combs(a)
    counts = (np.diff(np.sort(out,axis=1),axis=1)==0).sum(1)
    return out[counts == counts.min()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [161]: a = [np.array([1]),np.array([2]),np.array([2,3]),np.array([3]),\
     ...:                                 np.array([4]),np.array([3,4,5])]

In [162]: all_combs(a)  # Part-1 results
Out[162]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3],
       [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
       [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]])

In [163]: get_minrep_combs(a) # Part-2 results
Out[163]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Just to give you guys a sense of `all_combs`, here's a bit more "normal" sample case runs -

```
In [166]: a = [np.array([2,3]), np.array([5,6,7])]

In [167]: all_combs(a)
Out[167]: 
array([[2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 6],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 7]])

In [164]: a = [np.array([2,3,4]), np.array([5,6,7,9])]

In [165]: all_combs(a)
Out[165]: 
array([[2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 6],
       [4, 6],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 7],
       [2, 9],
       [3, 9],
       [4, 9]])
```

---

**For performance**

For performance, we can avoid the transpose in `part-1` and perform the operations in `part-2` along the columns `(axis=0)` and also use slicing to avoid `np.diff` and thus have one optimized version, like so -

```
def get_minrep_combs_optimized(a):   # Parte-1,2
    num_combs = np.prod(list(map(len,a)))
    out = np.array(np.meshgrid(*a)).reshape(-1,num_combs)  
    sorted_out = np.sort(out,axis=0)
    counts = (sorted_out[1:] == sorted_out[:-1]).sum(0)
    return out[:,counts == counts.min()].T
```

Sample run -

```
In [188]: a = [np.array([1]),np.array([2]),np.array([2,3]),np.array([3]),\
     ...:                                 np.array([4]),np.array([3,4,5])]

In [189]: get_minrep_combs_optimized(a)
Out[189]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]])
```

---

**Runtime test**

Here's one way to create a sample input data, which has upto `3` elems and each sub-list has *some* matches across elements in other sub-lists -

```
In [42]: lens = np.random.randint(1,4,(20))

In [43]: a = [np.random.randint(1,10,L) for L in lens]

In [44]: lens
Out[44]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3])

In [45]: a
Out[45]: 
[array([8]),
 array([8]),
 array([7, 9]),
 array([5, 5]),
 array([6, 4]),
 array([3, 1]),
 array([8]),
 array([1, 9]),
 array([9, 5, 7]),
 array([1, 1]),
 array([3]),
 array([1, 5]),
 array([5, 5]),
 array([7, 9, 2]),
 array([5]),
 array([1]),
 array([3, 2, 9]),
 array([3, 7]),
 array([5, 3]),
 array([2, 7, 3])]
```

Timings -

```
In [46]: %timeit leastReps(combinations(a)) #@Daniel Forsman's soln
1 loops, best of 3: 330 ms per loop

In [47]: %timeit get_minrep_combs_optimized(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.7 ms per loop
```

Let's have more matches -

```
In [50]: a = [np.random.randint(1,4,L) for L in lens]

In [51]: %timeit leastReps(combinations(a)) #@Daniel Forsman's soln
1 loops, best of 3: 328 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit get_minrep_combs_optimized(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.5 ms per loop
```

Doesn't change much for the performance difference.

Comment: That's a lot bigger performance difference than I get in my machine, but yours still seems to be faster (as always :( ).

Comment: @DanielForsman Would be nice to have timings from different systems I guess. Feel free to post timings from your end too alongwith the setup.

Comment: Nah, my test samples are smaller and I think my performance hit comes from the listwise `ravel()` which will only get bigger as the samples get bigger.  Not sure if finding the least repetitions or most uniques is more efficient though.

Comment: @DanielForsman Based on my testing, your part-1 is okay, but that second part of looping and finding unique ones isn't the best thing to do I guess.

Comment: Surprising, since you have the overhead of `sort`, but that seems to be the case.

Comment: I want to be able to use other structures as well (see, updated question), but that does not seem to work. I get the error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. Can you improve on your answer?

Comment: @Make42 Please post a new question on it.

Comment: Your solution does not work, if I have too many alternatives, I think: I get the error `ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function like this:

```
import itertools
from numpy import array
test = [array([1]),array([2]),array([2,3]),array([3]),array([4]),array([3,4,5])]
combinations = [list(tup) for tup in itertools.product(*test)]
print(combinations)
```

This returns:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3], 
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4], 
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3], 
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Part number 2 is not solvable, as there can be non-unique solutions...

Answer (score 1):

```
def combinations(arrList):
    mesh=np.meshgrid(*arrList)
    mesh=[arr.ravel() for arr in mesh]
    return np.array(mesh).T

def leastReps(combs):
    uniques=np.array([np.unique(arr).size for arr in list(combs)])
    mostUni = (uniques == np.max(uniques))
    return combs[mostUni]
```

Only difference between mine and Divakar's is that I don't need to calculate the number of products in advance, and I use most uniques and he uses least repetitions, which should be equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean by "most uniques" and "least repetitions"? Which one is more efficient?